# Does selelenium with python & beatifulsoup4 allow to load hidden elements from DOM explicitly like in jsoup?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup, jsoup

I am trying to use elements hidden from DOM and handle them using Selenium WebDriver and beatifulsoup.
I tried to use just simple sleep timers and expected conditions:

```
WebDriverWait(chrome, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mgm")))
```

But none of these options work.

Does this stack allow to load values from hidden elements like in code below?

```
String url = "https://www.facebook.com/cedarstreettimes?fref=ts";
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.33 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1438.7 Safari/537.33";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(ua).timeout(10*1000).get();

// move the hidden commented out html into the DOM proper:
Elements hiddenElements = doc.select("code.hidden_elem");
for (Element hidden: hiddenElements) {
    for (Node child: hidden.childNodesCopy()) {
        if (child instanceof Comment) {
            hidden.append(((Comment) child).getData()); // comment data parsed as html
        }
    }
}

Elements articles = doc.select("div[role=article]");
for (Element article: articles) {
    if (article.select("span.userContent").size() > 0) {
        String text = article.select("span.userContent").text();
        String imgUrl = article.select("div.photo img").attr("abs:src");
        System.out.println(String.format("%s\n%s\n\n", text,imgUrl));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "hidden" element from the `BeautifulSoup`'s perspective - it is not a browser and if there is an element present in the document, you can find it.

`selenium` would also locate the hidden elements and `presence_of_element_located` expected condition should fit here. You would not be able to interact with hidden elements, but would be able to extract the information inside them.